How to fill missing months with 0 values for given years in javascript?
data:
const data = [
  {time: "2020-10-13", value: 3},   
  {time: "2020-11-13", value: 30},  
  {time: "2021-01-13", value: 12}, 
  {time: "2021-02-13", value: 1},   
  {time: "2021-03-13", value: 23},   
  {time: "2021-04-13", value: 10}, ...
]

Im formating this data to this format: [number, number, number][] --> [month, year, value]
For the example data it would be:
[[11, 2020, 3], [10, 2020, 30], [1, 2021, 12], [2, 2021, 1], ...]

How can I add value 0 and month, when the month is missing? So in example, there is 10 months missing in 2020 and 9 months missing in 2021. I would like to add it so it looks like this:
[[1, 2020, 0], [2, 2020, 0],[3, 2020, 0], [4 2020, 0],[5, 2020, 30, [6, 2020, 0],[7, 2020, 0],[8, 2020, 0],[9, 2020, 0], [10, 2020, 30],[11, 2020, 3], [10, 2020, 30], [1, 2021, 12], [2, 2021, 1], ...]

What would be the best way to do it?
Thanks!!
EDIT:
some code I tried:
const months =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];
const res = data.flatMap(({time,value}) => {
  const [y,m,d] = time.split("-").map(Number); 
  const res = months.map((month, i) => {
    if (m === month) {
      return [m, y, value]
    } else {
      return [month, y, 0]
    }
  })
  return res;
})

const changeData = (data) => {
    let res = {};
     data.forEach((item) => {
       const {time, value} = item;
       const [y,m,d] = time.split("-").map(Number);
       res[y] !== undefined ? res[y].push({m, value})
       : res[y] = [{m, value}];
    })
    return res;
}
const newData = changeData(data);
console.log(newData)
const months =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];

const formatData = () => {
    let result = [];
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(newData)) {
        value.slice(0, 12).map((val, i) => {
            const y = key;
            const {m, value} = val;
            const res = months.map((month, i) => {
    
            if (m === month) {
                result.push([m, y, value]);
            } else {
              result.push([month, y, 0]);
            }
        })
        })     
    }
    return result;
}


What have you tried? We're not a code writing service. We expect that you'll do your research and make an attempt before posting here. Then, if you do post, we expect that you'll post what you've tried, along with a specific question about the issue you are facing. Just asking for a solution isn't how Stack Overflow works.

Your data variable seems to have elements that all include the month; can you [edit] your question to include realistic data where you would need to account for the month?

Iterate from whatever your arbitrary start date is, if you can find the month in your data, then construct the array you want from it, otherwise make a new one with value = 0, continue until you meet your end date.

const res = data.flatMap(({time,value}) => { const [y,m,d] = time.split("-").map(Number); const ret = Array.from({length: m-1}, (_, i) => [i+1,y,0]); ret.push([m,y,value]); return ret; }) idk something like this

Do you know the start and ending date for the time range?

You should change your data into an object whose keys are the dates. Then you can loop over the time range. For any month, check if it's in the object. If not, create an entry with value 0, otherwise use the value from the object.

@cmgchess thank you. Your solution does only fill UP to the existent month, not after (so if there is october and november present, it would fill only up to october). I tried to adjust your suggested code, but cant make it work

@Barmar I tried that (added it to my original question), but cant make it work

You should be looping over the time range, not the entries in the newData dictionary. For each month, check if it appears in newData. Use that value if it exists, otherwise default to 0.


const changeData = (data) => {
  let res = {};
    data.forEach((item) => {
      const {time, value} = item;
      const [y,m,d] = time.split("-").map(Number);
      if (!res[y]) {
        res[y] = {};
      }
      res[y][m] = item;
    })
    return res;
}
const newData = changeData(data);

const formatData = () => {
  let result = [];
  for (let year = 2020; year <= 2021; year++) {
    for (let month = 1; month <= 12; month++) {
      result.push([year, month, newData?.[year]?.[month]?.value || 0]);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
console.log(formatData());
<script>
const data = [
  {time: "2020-10-13", value: 3},   
  {time: "2020-11-13", value: 30},  
  {time: "2021-01-13", value: 12}, 
  {time: "2021-02-13", value: 1},   
  {time: "2021-03-13", value: 23},   
  {time: "2021-04-13", value: 10}
]
</script>




thank you but the data seems wrong..The not missing months for 2020 was October and November (10 & 11). In the data for these months its [
2020,
10,
0
], and [
2020,
11,
0
], with value being 0. It also added to 2020/01 (january) which was missing the value 30

I misread what your changeData() function does, I thought it was creating nested objects like {year: {month: value, ...}, ...}

This can be done using reduce(). Create all months for years first, then add value to them:


const data = [
  {time: "2020-10-13", value: 3},
  {time: "2020-11-13", value: 30},
  {time: "2021-01-13", value: 12},
  {time: "2021-02-13", value: 1},
  {time: "2021-03-13", value: 23},
  {time: "2021-04-13", value: 10},
]

const output = data.reduce((accumulator, current) => {
  if (!accumulator.length) {
    const years = Array.from(new Set(data.map(item => Number(item.time.split('-')[0]))));
    years.forEach(el => {
      for (let i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
        accumulator.push([i, el, 0]);
      }
    });
  }
  const [year, month] = current.time.split('-');
  const el = accumulator.find(
    o => o[0] === parseInt(month, 10) && o[1] === Number(year),
  );
  if (el) {
    el[2] += current.value;
  }
  return accumulator;
}, []);

console.log(output);



